Is there Any mention in scriptures of lord Chaitanya and his associates specifically performing only HareKrishna "sankirtan"(except just japa)
Please give me reference from sastras of lord chaitanya or his associates doing only HARE KRISHNA "SANKIRTAN"(i am talking about sankirtan nd not "japa(chanting on beads)" nd that too of Only Hare krishna mantra if lord chaitanya or his disciple's ever did it or recommended it)  for i have heard from a vaisnava that he only did and recommended JAPA(CHANTING ON BEADS) of Hare krishna and Sankirtan of some other Hari Naam Like "Hari haraye namah krishna Yadavaya namah...."etc "Govind jaya Jaya Gopala Jaya jaya" etc etc but "Hare krishna" being mahamantra was only meant for chanting on bead's at that time ......So i request to every people to please clear my doubt if they can from sastric reference's if lord chaitanya or his associates ever did Sankirtan Of Hare krishna
Thank u

Lord Chaitanya and His associates sang the various Holy Names of Lord Krishna including the Hare Krishna Maha Mantra.
This is evident from Lord Chaitanya's own writing i.e., Siksastakam where He considered all the Holy Names of Lord Hari to be powerful.

namnam akari bahudha nija-sarva-shaktis
tatrarpita niyamitah smarane na kalaha
etadrishi tava kripa bhagavan mamapi
durdaivam idrisham ihajani nanuragahah

O my Lord, Your holy name alone can render all benediction to living
beings, and thus You have hundreds and millions of names, like Krishna
and Govinda. In these transcendental names, you have invested all Your
transcendental energies. There are not even hard and fast rules for
chanting these names. O my Lord, out of kindness You enable us to
easily approach you by Your holy names, but I am so unfortunate that I
have no attraction for them.

The Hare Krishna Mahamantra is a Namatmaka Mantra which means it's simply the Lord's Holy Name in Mantra form and can thus be chanted or sung freely without any external considerations.
If it were a Beeja Mantra (such as starting with the Pranava, Klim, etc.), then various considerations would come into effect such as not chanting it loudly in Kirtana, internal and external cleanliness, and necessity of Diksa for the Mantra chanting to bear fruit.
Therefore, there is no reason why Lord Chaitanya & His associates would not have chanted the Hare Krishna Maha Mantra in Sankirtana along with all other Names of Lord Krishna.
When Lord Chaitanya asked Namacharya Srila Haridasa Thakura to describe the complete process of chanting the Hare Krishna Maha Mantra, he spoke the following words.

tulasi malaya nama sankhya kari smare; athava kirtana kare parama
adare
The Sadhaka should vow to chant and remember a fixed quantity of
rounds daily on a rosary made of tulasi beads. He can also chant or
sing some part of his daily quota in kirtana. He should do so with
great respect. (Harinam Chintamani Chapter 15 vsrse 35).
Many mahājanas engaged in smaraṇa by chanting some amount of Names on
beads, and some amount through nāma–kīrtana. The advantage of kīrtana
is that one engages in śravaṇa, smaraṇa and kīrtana – one performs
three limbs of bhakti simultaneously.
eka grantha sankhyā kari ārambhibe nāma krame tina lakṣa smari pūre
manaskāma
“One should begin by chanting one grantha of Names. Gradually one will
meditate upon three lakhs of the Holy Names and all desires will be
fulfilled.(HNC 15.36)*
*Translators Note: A grantha is four rounds of japa. Three lakhs is 192 rounds.
sankhyā madhye kichu nāma karibe kīrtana tāte sarvendriya sphūrti
ānanda-nartana
Amongst this prescribed number of chanting Harinan, some Names are to be sung in kīrtana.
In this way, all the senses will dance in bliss (HNC 15.37)

PS: For anyone interested to know about Sadhana of the Hare Krishna Maha Mantra, I highly suggest reading Sri Harinam Chintamani which describes the basics all the way up to attaining one's svarupa in Goloka Vrindavan.
